# Apache2.4.11 virtualhostconfiguration is not working

Tags: php, linux, apache, lamp, httpd.conf

I have tried the below code to point the domain name to specific directory into linux

```
NameVirtualHost *.80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but the above code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above code is for apache2.2, so you just replace above code with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName     example.com
   ServerAlias    www.example.com
   ServerAdmin    root@example.com
   DocumentRoot   "/var/www/html/example.com"
   CustomLog      "/var/www/html/example.com/access_log" combined
   ErrorLog       "/var/www/html/example.com/error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you run a2ensite exemple.com.conf? Restart apache after that.